# How much modification is needed to be considered authoring the code?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope, code-ownership

In [C++ PEXT/PDEP implementations](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/278954/c-pext-pdep-implementations?noredirect=1#comment552576_278954)

I believe that significant changes were made. But there was a comment stating that modifying is off topic.

As this code is public, then modifications should be considered maintaining the code. And it should be clear that I do understand how it works.

In fact, unless there is something I missed, I plan on making a pull request to update the git repository.

The assembly is significantly different, enough that most programmers would take a good while to assert they are functionally equivent.So it is not just changing variable names, or trivially rearranging the code.

I will of course remove the post if the consensus is that it is off topic.

Comment: One person has commented on your question with a concern. The concern seems to be a misrepresentation of the provided link "Am I an author or maintainer of the code?" not "if you are not the author of the code you post, it's not considered on-topic for CodeReview". I don't think discussing whether your question is on/off topic will be beneficial at the moment. Once more people step forward and vote your question as off-topic, I think there'd be a point to the discussion.

Comment: One of the things you seem to be miss understanding is that there are copyright laws involved. If you do a pull request and the owner of the repository merges the code in yes you become a maintainer of that code. Until that happens you are not a maintainer of the original code.

Comment: Glenn, I don't think there is anything wrong with your code, but apart from the authorship requirement making it possibly off-topic, I also don't know what you expect out of this review? You clearly know it's about the performance of this code, and you probably already measured yourself what the gain is. And the code style was chosen so it conforms to the rest of the original bitops.hh, so I don't think there's much useful to say about that either.

Comment: To me, it seems that what's reviewable is the _delta_ between the original and modified versions (as that's the part that's the asker's work), so it's worth looking at [Is a changeset reviewable?](/q/9335/75307) and [Is asking for code review on a patch file OK?](/q/144/75307) for some advice.  In this case, given that the intention is to make a pull-request, that is obviously inviting a code review from the project maintainer(s) (who will certainly want consistency with the project's existing style, layout and architecture), so asking here is probably unnecessary at best.

Comment: I'm disturbed to see that "_most programmers would take a good while to assert they are functionally [equivalent]_".  Is there some reason that the unit tests don't provide the required confidence?  Perhaps they should be improved before changing the implementation?